# Why is my Java Morse Code translator giving me the wrong output?

Tags: java, morse-code

I have seen many questions about the Morse Code translator floating around and have looked at many of them, but in all of them the suggested answer gives me the same incorrect output. The idea behind the code is to be able to translate Morse Code to English and vice versa using arrays. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main ( String [] args )
{

    String [] morse = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "|"};

    String [] english =  { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", " "};

    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System. in );
    System.out.println ( "Enter 1 to translate Morse Code to English or 2 to translate English to Morse Code:");
    int userChoice = input.nextInt();
    String translateMe;

    while (userChoice < 1 || userChoice > 2 ) // Ensures user enters a valid choice
    {
        System.out.println( "Not a valid entry. Enter 1 to translate Morse Code to English or 2 to translate English to Morse Code:");
        userChoice = input.nextInt();
    }

   if (userChoice == 1 )
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a Morse Code statement to translate. Separate letters with spaces and words with a ' | '" );
        translateMe = input.next();

        String [] morseChar = translateMe.split(" ");

        for( int x = 0; x < morseChar.length; x++)
        {
            String letter = morseChar[ x ];
            for ( int index = 0; index < morse.length; index++ )
            {
                if(morse [ index ].equals(letter))
                {
                    System.out.print(english[ index ]); // Display character at matching index position of English array to show translation
                }
            }
        }

        }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an English statement to translate:");
        translateMe = input.next();
        translateMe = translateMe.toLowerCase();

        String [] englishChar = translateMe.split("(?!^)");

        for ( int x = 0; x < englishChar.length; x++)
        {
            String letter = englishChar [ x ];

            for (int index = 0; index < english.length; index++)
            {
                if( english [index].equals( letter ))
                {
                    System.out.print(morse[index] + " "); // Display Morse Code array character at matching index position to show translation
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

I have been using the phrase

`to be`

and its Morse Code counterpart

`- --- | -… .`

as a test phrase. When I try translating English to Morse Code with this phrase I get

`... -.`  s and n

as the output. When I try Morse Code to English, I get

`u`

as the output. I have gone over my two String arrays to make sure `morse[A]` and `english[A]` are in the same index position and so on, and those are fine. I can't think of anything else that would cause this problem.

Edit: It may be helpful to know I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation from morse to English is not working due to your use of Scanner.  You need to use nextLine() as follows:

```
if (userChoice == 1 )
{
    translateMe = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter a Morse Code statement to translate. Separate letters with spaces and words with a ' | '" );
    translateMe = input.nextLine();
```

After that, it seems to translate fine, even with the split command.

Output:

```
[.-, -..., -.-.]
abc
```

Output 2:

```
Please enter a Morse Code statement to translate. Separate letters with spaces and words with a ' | '
- --- | -... .
[-, ---, |, -..., .]
to be
```

Comment: This works perfectly for English to Morse, but Morse to English I'm missing the 'b'

Comment: Sorry Jes, what do you mean by missing the 'b'?

Comment: Ah, sorry, the 'b' from my 'to be' test (from Morse to English) is missing. I've been using that as a test phrase.

Comment: Ah... OK, let me try to map "to be" back and forth and see what I get.

Comment: If it helps, all other inputs seem to work fine both ways. Even 'b' on it's own and other 'b' containing words.

Comment: I did not have a problem with mapping "to be" (see output 2 above).  Are you sure you removed the extra morse 'n' from the array?

Comment: When I typed in the Morse Code, my output is fine. I was copy and pasting before, so that must have been the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.  Scanner can be tricky.  When you use getInt(), and then want to read a String line, you need to use Scanner as you do now.

Answer (score 1):

1. The code for `n` (`"-."`) appears twice in your array.
2. You are probably better off converting the String into a `char[]`. You'd have to change the alphabet from `String[]` to `char[]`.
3. This is why we have `Map`.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I missed it from staring at it so long. I now get the morse output for 'to' and english output 't', so my translator is stopping way too early. Any ideas?

Comment: See @Ian 's comment. That will explain the missing output.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the output you get--while I haven't tried running it, by eyeballing it I see a very different result.

Fundamentally, though, your morse-to-English translator is matching too early.  You need to check the whole string.

Edit:  Now nothing obvious sticks out, have you tried stepping through it with the debugger to see what's actually going on?

Comment: My apologies, I had posted a previous version of my code. I have edited the original code to what I have currently. This version (I think) runs through the whole user input. However, both versions give me the same incorrect output.

Comment: Debugger gives me '- --- Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61223', transport: 'socket'' but I honestly have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting "s" and "n" from the english translation is because if we inspect the word "to", the previous letter in the alphabet to "t" is "s" and the previous in the alphabet to "o" is "n", so that leads me to believe there is a looping error in there.  Additionally, you're using "next()" instead of "nextLine()" so you're not parsing what you think you are.  I think if you use "nextLine()" and fix your loop, you'll have it.  Thanks for providing full source code!  :D

Here's how I tested:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main ( String [] args )
{

    String [] morse = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "|"};

    String [] english =  { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", " "};

    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System. in );
    System.out.println ( "Enter 1 to translate Morse Code to English or 2 to translate English to Morse Code:");
    int userChoice = input.nextInt();
    String translateMe;

    while (userChoice < 1 || userChoice > 2 ) // Ensures user enters a valid choice
    {
        System.out.println( "Not a valid entry. Enter 1 to translate Morse Code to English or 2 to translate English to Morse Code:");
        userChoice = input.nextInt();
    }

    if (userChoice == 1 )
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a Morse Code statement to translate. Separate letters with spaces and words with a ' | '" );
        translateMe = input.next();

        String [] morseChar = translateMe.split(" ");

        for( int x = 0; x < morseChar.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Comparing " + morseChar + " to the morse array");
            for ( int index = 0; index < morse.length; index++ )
            {
                System.out.println("Comparing equality of: " + morseChar[x] + " and " + morse[index]);
                if(morseChar[x].equals(morse[index]))
                {
                    System.out.print(english[ index ]); // Display character at matching index position of English array to show translation
                }
            }
        }

    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an English statement to translate:");
        translateMe = input.next();
        translateMe = translateMe.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(" Translating:  [" + translateMe + "]");

        System.out.println("Translating: " + translateMe);
        String[] englishChar = translateMe.split(" ");

        for(String s : englishChar) {
            System.out.println("Translation String: " + s);
        }

        for ( int x = 0; x < englishChar.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Checking word: " + englishChar[x]);
            for (int index = 0; index < english.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Comparing equality of: " + englishChar[x] + " and " + english[index] + " they are " + (englishChar [ x ].equals( english[index]) ? " equal" :  " not equal"));
                if( englishChar [ x ].equals( english[index]))
                {
                    System.out.print(morse[index] + " "); // Display Morse Code array character at matching index position to show translation
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}